# Set threshold to trigger or stop summing the data points in C

Tags: arrays, c, sum, threshold

I'm trying to mimic when my data acquision card acquiring data with data streaming mode and do the data processing. The `pi16Buffer` means the long wave form data of mixed channel1 and channel2, so I used `for` loop to `de-interleave` the data to `ch1Buffer[i]` and `ch2Buffer[i]`. Second, normalized the `ch1Buffer` by `ch2Buffer`, call them `Corrected`. According to the `Corrected` value, used `if` to trigger to `sum` the value to calculate the `Area under curve`. However, what I got are all `0`, please check my example code if there are any setting wrong? I suppose to get 3 summed value from the `AUC`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
float* ch1Buffer = NULL;
float* ch2Buffer = NULL;
float AUC;

int main()
{
    int i;
    const int u32Size = 62;
    float Corrected;
    
    
    //int pBuffer[] = { 10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,0};
    int pBuffer[] = { 0,10,1,10,1,10,0,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,1,10,0,10,0,10,1,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,0,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,1,10};
    int* pi16Buffer = pBuffer;


    
    
    ch1Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch1Buffer);
    ch2Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
    
    

    // De-interleave the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
    {
        ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
        ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
    }

    
    


    
    Corrected = ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];
    
    if (Corrected > 0.1)
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++) {
            AUC += Corrected;
        }
    else
        AUC = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++) {
        printf("%f ", AUC);
    }

    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't change your code once an answer has been posted. It invalidates the answer. If the answer helped you, accept it and upvote. Then ask a new question with your updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in this part:

```
// De-interleave the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
{
    ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
    ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
}

Corrected = ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];  // not good ...
```

When the loop completes the value of `i` is `u32Size/2` and nothing has been assigned to `ch1Buffer[i]`. In other words - `ch1Buffer[i]` is zero due to use of `calloc`. The same applies to `ch2Buffer[i]`.

So you are doing:

```
Corrected = 0.0 / 0.0;  // not good
```

Further, this code

```
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++) {
        AUC += Corrected;
    }
```

is strange.. you keep adding the same value in the loop.

Maybe  the line: `Corrected = ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];` should have been inside the for-loop.

BTW: You allocate `u32Size` elements to the arrays but you only use half of them.

Comment: But I checked with `print` to `ch1Buffer[i]` and `ch2Buffer[i]` both of them are holding the value which I expected. Why do you say they are `0`?

Comment: OK I got your point, I should put `Corrected = ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];` into the `for` loop.

Comment: I updated my code. The `AUC` values no longer be `0` now, but the value is `2.4` which was not what I expecting `2.3`. Maybe the threshold mechanism I set wasn't right?